# Given a T and function name and type, how can I resolve T::function?

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

Given an `Event` struct and an object that implements a function with a specific name and prototype, known by the `Event` struct, I want to return a pointer or bind to that function. Exactly what it returns doesn't matter; it can just as easily be a pointer-to-member-function or a bind.

It's a bit hard to explain, so here's some psuedo-code:

```
struct Foo {
    void onEvent();
};

struct Bar {
    void onEvent();
};

struct Event
{
    // I'm not sure what would go here
    // Needs something that can be used to resolve T::onEvent, without
    // knowing what T is until GetEventFunction is called.
    typedef std::function<void()> function_type;
};

template<typename T, typename EventType>
EventType::function_type GetEventFunction(T* object)
{
    return std::bind(T::(EventType::Something), object);
}

GetEventFunction<Foo, Event>(new Foo); // Returns Foo::onEvent
GetEventFunction<Bar, Event>(new Bar); // Returns Bar::onEvent
```

Can this behavior be achieved, or is C++ too limited to allow this?

**Please read this before answering**

I am not looking for reflection. As far as I'm aware, all of the information needed to do what I'm aiming for is available at compile time.

Also, I am not interested in alternate approaches. I know many ways to achieve this behavior with additional code, such as template specializations for each Event type, but I'm looking for a way to achieve this specifically.

Comment: Cannot be done. I guess *C++ is too limited* for you.

Comment: You claim you're not interested in alternatives, but I still say you may be suffering from the XY problem. Especially considering what you're trying to express with what is the scope resolution operator, which works with identifiers, not types.

Comment: I have 100 `Event` structs. I have an `EventHandler<T>` object, which is given a callback to be called when event `T` is raised. I want to be able to just pass an object, and have the compiler resolve `T::onEventType` for me.

Comment: @dauphic: The design cannot be implemented as is. The solution is registering functors (`std::function<void(X)>` where `X` represents the arguments required by this callback). Then when registering the event handlers you can use `std::bind` to map the appropriate object/member

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Maybe I didn't explain well, but the function name is unique for each `Event` type. A `FooEvent` should resolve `T::onFooEvent`, while a `BarEvent` should resolve `T::onBarEvent`.

C++ can operate on types and values, but not on *names*. That's dealing with text, which is a macro-level thing that happens before C++ proper gets to look at the code. You can't take the type `BarEvent` and convert it into the function `T::onBarEvent`, because there is no association between them except for what they happen to be *named*.

That's why Luc's answer used a specific name: names of functions have to be hard-coded.

Now, you can side-step C++'s rules a bit via the use of a traits template. For example, you can create an `event_traits` template type that has a member function which takes `T` and calls a specific function on it. It would look like this:

```
template<typename event_type>
struct event_traits
{
  template<typename T> void Dispatch(T *t) {t->DefaultEventFunction();}
};
```

The above uses `DefaultEventFunction`.

If you want each `Event` to have its own event function, you'll need a specialization for each `Event` class. And if you want to enforce this rule, simply never define `DefaultEventFunction` in any of your `T` objects; the compiler will complain. Change the name into something unlikely to be used, like `WhyDidYouNameThisFunctionLikeThisStopIt`.

```
template<>
struct event_traits<FooEvent>
{
  template<typename T> void Dispatch(T *t) {t->onFooEvent();}
};

template<>
struct event_traits<BarEvent>
{
  template<typename T> void Dispatch(T *t) {t->onBarEvent();}
};
```

This is where macros can come in handy:

```
#define REGISTER_EVENT_HANDLER(eventName)\
template<> struct event_traits<eventName>\
{\
  template<typename T> void Dispatch(T *t) {t->on ## eventName ();}\
};
```

Thus, your `GetEventFunction` would look like this:

```
template<typename T, typename EventType>
EventType::function_type GetEventFunction(T* object)
{
    return std::bind(event_traits<EventType>::Dispatch<T>, object);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do have the *name* of the member, then you don't need to know of a type -- assuming that member is not an overloaded member function.

```
template<typename T>
auto GetEventFunction(T& object)
-> decltype( std::bind(&T::onEvent, std::ref(object)) )
{ return std::bind(&T::onEvent, std::ref(object)); }

// Usage:
Foo f;
auto event = GetEventFunction(f);
```

Note that this is somewhat contrived, because the `onEvent` you mentioned doesn't take any arguments. If it did, you'd need more scaffolding. (I'd recommend writing a `mem_fn` that also accepts an object, unlike `std::mem_fn`.)

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well, but the function name is unique for each `Event` type. A `FooEvent` should resolve `T::onFooEvent`, while a `BarEvent` should resolve `T::onBarEvent`.